# Is user experience designed to make humans lazy?

Tags: user-behavior, user-centered-design, best-practice, cognitive-load

Let's say for example, in a railway station a sign board displays the arrival of train. Let's take two scenarios.

Scenario 1
The sign board displays "train 1 arriving at 9:35"
Scenario 2
The sign board displays "train 1 arriving in 5 minutes"(assuming the time is 9:30)

Between these two scenarios, many people I asked for, has voted for the second scenario citing better user experience.
My question is, doesn't it make the human lazy to think?

Comment: So you think for every trivial activity we should create an inextricable puzzle just to *make humans not lazy*? If so, well, UX is the absolute opposite to that

Comment: Suppose a toaster was so complicated that I spent all day at home making a piece of toast, then I'd be that lazy guy that made a piece of toast all day. But with good user experience that toaster takes a minute and I can go about my day doing all kinds of things. A bit hyperbolic but it simplifies the idea that a good UX simplifies tasks so that users can quickly and easily accomplish many tasks.

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, because you're discussing travel, the second "Train arriving in X minutes" eliminates any issues with travelers from different time zones.

it's not about "lazy" it's about eliminating the potential for confusion and miscommunication.

Answer (score 5):

> **User experience design** (UX, UXD, UED or XD) is the process of enhancing user satisfaction with a product by improving the usability, accessibility, and pleasure provided in the interaction with the product.

Enhancing user satisfaction is not about making users lazy. It is about facilitating the way we use product or services to be as efficient as possible to its purpose.

> **Efficiency** is the (often measurable) ability to avoid wasting materials, energy, efforts, money, and time in doing something or in producing a desired result. In a more general sense, it is the ability to do things well, successfully, and without waste.

Reducing the time and effort to accomplish something, prevents mistakes and gives us the opportunity of using that time to do a second task, whatever it is.

So it is more in terms of **being able to achieve more tasks because there are thoughtful decisions behind the overall design**, versus achieving less because the way to accomplish the tasks is unintuitive and might end up in conflicts.

---

[User experience design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design).

[Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency).